# Remove milliseconds from time datatype and also: is there a millisecond-less time datatype?

Tags: sql-server-2008, types, time, type-conversion

I have seen posts in the question on how to remove milliseconds from the datetime datatype in MS SQL.

But what about the time datatype - what is the easiest way to remove milliseconds from the time datatype?

Also: Is there any time datatype in MS SQL (2008) that doesn't include milliseconds?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> One of the easiest way to remove milliseconds is:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 20)
```

> And if you dont want to include milliseconds:

```
TIME(0) will help
```

> Example

```
CAST(DATEADD(second, SUM(hora), '00:00:00') AS time(0))
```

Comment: This came up very handy. Elegant and effective.

Comment: This is really effective. Other solutions I've found, it still show the last 3 digits as 000.

Answer (score 0):

What I did to solve this for MS SQL server 2005 is

```
create table mytable (Date varchar(11))

insert into mydb.mytable select GETDATE() as Date;
```

This cuts some of the value from GETDATE() off, right after the last number in the year part. i.e. 'Jan 09 2014'.

edit: to be clear, varchar(11) is the solution here.

edit: this solution sucks if you have to join on mysql CURDATE(), because mysql returns all integers while MSSQL Server has the alphabetic month.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to return the time in sql server 2005 You could use a substring function with the convert i.e. SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),20),12,8). 
This will return the time in the format hh:mm:ss.